# Flutter how to get all the days of the week as string in the users locale

Tags: flutter

AS stated in the title: Is there an easy way to get all the days of the week as string(within a list ofcourse) in the users locale?

Answer (score 13):

Using the intl package, the easiest way I found would be:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

var days = DateFormat.EEEE(Platform.localeName).dateSymbols.STANDALONEWEEKDAYS;

print(days)  // => ["Sunday", "Monday", ..., "Saturday"]
```

You can replace `STANDALONEWEEKDAYS` with `WEEKDAYS` to get the names as they would appear within a sentence (e.g. first letter lowercase in some languages).

Also, you may use `SHORTWEEKDAYS` and `STANDALONESHORTWEEKDAYS` respectively to get the weekday abbreviations. For even shorter abbreviations, use `NARROWWEEKDAYS` or `STANDALONENARROWWEEKDAYS`.

Comment: Nice and sweet solution, but since sunday is not first item according to ISO 8601 which DateTime uses. So to use this list, move sunday to the end of the list.

Answer (score 12):

My suggestion is:

```
static List<String> getDaysOfWeek([String locale]) {
  final now = DateTime.now();
  final firstDayOfWeek = now.subtract(Duration(days: now.weekday - 1));
  return List.generate(7, (index) => index)
      .map((value) => DateFormat(DateFormat.WEEKDAY, locale)
          .format(firstDayOfWeek.add(Duration(days: value))))
      .toList();
}
```

The idea is *we define the date of the first day in the current week* depending on current week day. Then just do loop 7 times starting from calculated date, add 1 day on each iteration and collect the result of [DateFormat()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html).[format](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat/format.html) method with pattern DateFormat.[WEEKDAY](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat/WEEKDAY-constant.html). To increase performance you can use lazy initialization. For example:

```
/// Returns a list of week days
static List<String> _daysOfWeek;
static List<String> get daysOfWeek {
  if (_daysOfWeek == null) {
    _daysOfWeek = getDaysOfWeek(); // Here you can specify your locale
  }
  return _daysOfWeek;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. RemembeAr that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 3):

After doing:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

String localeName = "pt_BR"; // "en_US" etc.
initializeDateFormatting(localeName);
```

Use this:

```
static List<String> weekDays(String localeName) {    
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat(DateFormat.WEEKDAY, localeName);
    return [DateTime(2000, 1, 3, 1), DateTime(2000, 1, 4, 1), DateTime(2000, 1, 5, 1),
      DateTime(2000, 1, 6, 1), DateTime(2000, 1, 7, 1), DateTime(2000, 1, 8, 1),
      DateTime(2000, 1, 9, 1)].map((day) => formatter.format(day)).toList();
}
```

I'm not sure it qualifies as "easy". Maybe someone here can come up with a better answer.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the current day or month localized with your phone settings

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

final String defaultLocale = Platform.localeName; // Phone local
// String defaultLocale = "pt_BR"; // "en_US" etc. you can define yours as well

// add to init 
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initializeDateFormatting(defaultLocale);
} 

static String _getLocalizedWeekDay(String local, DateTime date) {
    final formatter = DateFormat(DateFormat.WEEKDAY, local);
    return formatter.format(date);
}

static String _getLocalizedMonth(String local, DateTime date) {
    final formatter = DateFormat(DateFormat.MONTH, local);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```