# Flutter function ended with variable name

Tags: flutter

I'm itinerating though this map and trying to internationalize my app:

```
Map<String, bool> map = {
'monday': true,
'tuesday': true,
'wednesday': true,
'thursday': true,
'friday': true,
'saturday': true,
'sunday': true,
};
```

The expected result is:

```
Monday: true,
Tuesday: true
```

But if the user changes to spanish for example I will like to show:
Lunes: true,
Martes: true

So how can I do the following?:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).(here put the value of the map ex monday)
=> AppLocalizations.of(context).mapvalue
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270014/flutter-how-to-get-all-the-days-of-the-week-as-string-in-the-users-locale)

Comment: The question title doesn't seem to match the content; there's no function and no variable name.

Comment: This question lacks a bit of context. How are you printing the days? In order to "internationalize" your app, you'll have to rethink your app structure. You will want to reserve actual translations to displayable content and not data structures.

Comment: Okey, I will rethink the app structure to make it better! Thanks :)